# How can i make dual monitors with VGA and DVI-D ports?

Tags: multiple-monitors, graphics-card, vga, dvi, nvidia-geforce

I have a [Gigabyte GV-N640OC-2GI](http://uk.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=4255) graphics card with 2 monitors:

- An older Asus LCD with VGA port only. This works fine, plugged into the graphics card VGA slot.
- A Dell 1801FP monitor with a DVI-D port. (Got VGA too, but I have to use the DVI-D.)

I have a VGA to VGA cable with [DVI-D adapters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XvCjh.jpg),
so I tried to use them to turn my VGA to VGA cable to a DVI-D to DVI-D cable.

I attached one adapter to the monitor, and the other one to the card's DVI-D port, but it doesn't work. My Windows 7 doesn't recognise it. The NVIDIA Control panel neither. The screen stays blank too.

When I unplug the older Asus, and simply use the VGA cables and ports, it works, but I need both monitors.

I tried to unplug the Asus monitor and just use the DVI-D ports, but that doesn't work either.

Is the problem with the cable? Which cable do I need to make this monitor work on the DVI-D port?

Comment: Get a real DVI-D cable?

Comment: Yes, it's most likely the cable or the adapters. Use the cable without the adapters with the Asus LCD and see if it works. If it doesn't, then it's the adapters.

Comment: *" I tried to use them to turn my VGA to VGA cable to a DVI-D to DVI-D cable."* -- That won't work.  Those aren't VGA-to-DVI-D adapters; they're for DVI-I.  The graphics card has a DVI-I port which has both digital video (for DVI-D) and analog video (for VGA).  You need to use a real DVI-D cable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you used "I attached one adapter to the monitor, and the other one to the card's DVI-D port, but it doesn't work. My Windows 7 doesn't recognise it. The NVIDIA Control panel neither. The screen stays blank too." this on the second monitor i.e. Dell 1801FP monitor.
and "When I unplug the older Asus, and simply use the VGA cables and ports, it works, but I need both monitors." then this means that your VGA cable is working properly. Then if your VGA cable is working properly then try to first use that cable on the VGA port of second screen. If it's working then maybe your DVI-D adapters are faulty (I assume that Dell monitor is a new one so the DVI ports should not be the fault).
And also "My Windows 7 doesn't recognise it. The NVIDIA Control panel neither" I think that you also got an IGD (nowadays mostly all of the computers have an integrated graphics card built-in) so also check whether to change the input when you plug-in the DVI-ports and select your default graphics card in the BIOS to be another one(external one) and then try to see if it works. Also if this doesn't work then first check if your DVI-ports from the graphics card are alright and you are plugging in correctly.

Also if you windows cannot recognise it maybe because you haven't installed the graphics driver of the Card

Comment: One thing I forgot in the answer that if windows cannot use your graphics card ,i.e. if your graphics card isn't in use then how NVIDIA control panel is opening. As far as I know that NVIDIA control panel doesn't open if their isn't any NVIDIA GC available.

Comment: My graphics card is working, the NVIDIA control panel recognises it.
I did nothing and after a few days the control panel and the windows recognised the monitor, however it still blank and looking for signal, so I ordered a real cable, I'm sure thats the weak spot now, so thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that you cannot put a VGA monitor (analog) into a DVI-D (digital Only Port). nothing will work I presume.   I think it should if it was a dvi-I port which is digital and analog or just dvi-a which is analog only.

Comment: sure you can, with a vga to dvi converter. they are like 5 bucks and normally come free with the purchase of a video card.

Answer (score 0):

VGA is analog. Dvi-d can receive digital signal only. Dvi-a can accept a VGA cable with adapter, but these are less common now. It was only an intermediary technology as we were transitioning from VGA to newer technology such as Dvi and later hdmi. Dvi-I can accept both analog and digital, but your monitor doesn't support that.

You can see the different [dvi connector types here](
http://www.datapro.net/techinfo/dvi_info.html).